# SVG textContent not changing when selected by id

Tags: javascript, svg

I made a simple SVG text element and want to change the text dynamically through javascript.

```
text.id = 'unitNumbersTer1';
text.textContent = '1';
```

And later on:

```
d3.select('#unitNumbersTer1').textContent = '0';
```

However, the text does not change. It simply stays at '1'. I've also tried

```
d3.select('#unitNumbersTer1').text('0');
```

which gave the same result,

```
document.getElementById('unitNumbersTer1').textContent = '2';
```

which gives me a "TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null",

```
var svg = document.getElementById("gameBoardSVG");
var svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
var circle = svgDoc.getElementById('unitNumbersTer1');
```

which gave me a "TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined", and

```
text.setAttributeNS(null, "id", 'unitNumbersTer1');
```

instead of the text.id way to try to assign an id, but all results are the same. Why does textContent work when immediately set, but not when referred to by the element id?

Comment: If you have the variable `text` in your script, why not use that?

Comment: Because it's an embedded variable used when dynamically creating the text element, so I can't use it outside the function this whole code is placed in ( var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','text'); )

Comment: But... you can't access an element that isn't there either? Are you trying to fetch an element by ID before it's added to the DOM? After it's added, you already have a reference to it in `text` ?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? Something that actually runs e.g. a stack snippet.

Comment: It seems my issue was with the fact that I tested all this before appending the text to the SVG element. When doing this before changing the textContent, everything seems to work as intended.